# How to add valid class to the dependent element on success of dependee in jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two textboxes, Phone number, `#inputPh`, and email, `#inputEm`. Either one of these is mandatory.  I'm using the following rules:

```
         rules: {

                inputPhone: {                           
                        required: {depends: function(){
                        if($("#inputEm").val()=="")//return value based on textbox1 status
                        return true;
                        else
                        return false;
                            }
                        },
                        isNum: true,
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength: 12
                    },        
               inputEmail: {
                        required: {depends: function(){
                        if($("#inputPh").val()=="")//return value based on textbox1 status
                        return true;
                        else
                        return false;
                            }
                        },
                        email: true
                    }
         },
         highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');

        },
        success: function(element) {
                    element.addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');

        }
```

The validation works fine, but the problem is that when the form is submitted with empty fields, both the textboxes will be highlighed with the error class. Afterwards when I enter a valid value in either one of the textboxes, only that particulor field gets the success class, and the other one will have the error class, even though the form can be submitted.

How can I access or pass the dependent element through jQuery Validator functions?

Comment: If the validation works fine, then what's the real problem?  Why is having the error class remain on the submitted field an issue in this case?

Comment: _"How can i access or pass the dependent element through jquery validator functions?"_  ~  What does this even mean?  Describe what behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: there are 2 textboxes, one is required if the other is empty. when a valid input is given in the second textbox, i want to give both thetext boxes succes class. but i can only access the current element- which is the second textbox using jquery validate plugin..

Comment: To fix your issues with the error & valid classes, use the `require_from_group` method.  Also, you should be showing your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use the `require_from_group` method included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).  As per the code comments:

```
/*
 * Lets you say "at least X inputs that match selector Y must be filled."
 *
 * The end result is that neither of these inputs:
 *
 *  <input class="productinfo" name="partnumber">
 *  <input class="productinfo" name="description">
 *
 *  ...will validate unless at least one of them is filled.
 *
 * partnumber:  {require_from_group: [1,".productinfo"]},
 * description: {require_from_group: [1,".productinfo"]}
 *
 */
```

There will not be any issues with the error class remaining on the other field...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            inputPhone: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
                // isNum: true, // <-- no such rule in this plugin
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 12
            },
            inputEmail: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wWjWM/**

Optionally, you can use the `groups` option to consolidate the messages for both fields into one label.  However, this may not be desirable because it will also apply to all other rules on both fields.

BTW:  There are various phone numbers rules in the `additional-methods.js` file that you can use in place of `minlength` and `maxlength`.  (there is also no such rule as `isNum` in this plugin.  It's called `digits`.)

Comment: i was in a hurry to find some sort of solution, so i forgot to add the html markup and mention that isNum is a custom method i've added to math a regex for phone number. thank you for the answer and your effort... it works! :)